# Single responsibility principle and Backbone.View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, single-responsibility-principle

I use Backbone.js. I have popup1, which creates popup2. popup2 is component-like and when it closes it triggers the event 'school_address:saved'. I need to send a request to the server on 'school_address:saved' event. I placed the handler which do so in the view of the popup1 (its instance still exists), but I'm not sure that this place is appropriate, because views are responsible for template UI logic, aren't they?.

What do you think is the best place for such code? And what would it be if I used Marionette.js?

Comment: Do you have some model in your views? Can be this "request to the server" related to data in model? If so I think the best place for this logic is inside model and views will be just listen events in this model.

Comment: Do you have some model in your views? – Yes, in each popup. But because of "componential" nature of popup2 I can't modify its model, because this request on event of popup2 is necessary only when popup1 instantiates popup2.

Comment: Can be this "request to the server" related to data in model? – No, it's an empty request. Just to alert the server, that popup2 was handled.

Answer (score 0):

We have been using BackboneJS for a few years now and have wondered about similar cases in the past...

Since BackboneJS (unlike other JS frameworks)does not enforce any common way of doing this, I would generally say this really depends on your implementation and application flow.

However, since these are popups/"application modals", I think it would help if you consider the following based on your current need:

1. If it is ONLY **popup1** that can instantiate and display **popup2**, then have popup1 listenTo the events triggered by popup2.
2. If you foresee your application flow changes, and possibly having popup2 display elsewhere, or independently, I would suggest you listen to popup2 events from a view at a higher level (possibly one you have a route for). this way, both of your popups will be "independent", and you could recycle their code more easily and support greater flexibility as your application grows.

Comment: Not only popup1 can instantiate and display popup2, but I need to send that request only if it's popup1.

It's not possible to listen to that event in a view on a higher level, because popups can be created in different "environments".

So according to your answer I suppose that my chose was right (to place handler to the popup1).

But why don't you think that router is appropriate?

Comment: in different "environments"
– I mean different pages. And because of specific of the project there is no layout view and I'm not sure, that such place would be appropriate, because of its globality.

Comment: If it's a "general" listener, waiting for events from popup2, you can place that code pretty much anywhere. it does not have to be in any view - it can simply be binded using a global function somewhere, not necessarily  from within the router...

If the event is triggered from multiple places (not only from within popup2) I would simply pass another argument along with the event payload, to distinguish between triggers coming out of popup2 or from other places in the app, along with a condition for the event functionality to check for the value provided in the payload.